# Spring Security SAML2 multiple IDP but unique assertion consumer service

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0

We are developing SAML authentication with many identity providers with Spring Security SAML2.
The metadata file of our service provider is unique and it will be distributed to all identity providers, so we need to have unique endpoint for the assertion consumer service.

The yaml configuration is like:

```
spring:   
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          idpone:
            identityprovider:
              metadata-uri: "classpath:metadata/idp/metadata-idp1.xml"
          idptwo:
            identityprovider:
              metadata-uri: "classpath:metadata/idp/metadata-idp2.xml"
```

We tryed to add for every idp

```
acs:
  location: "{baseUrl}/login/saml2/sso"
```

but the url `{baseUrl}/login/saml2/sso` results not found.

How can we configure it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the correct url is {baseUrl}/login/saml2/idpone or {baseUrl}/login/saml2/idptwo